# Using function result inside expression function used by a predicate

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am trying to use predicateBuilder with next expression definition but I always got the message
"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'puedeConsultar' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."
I think i understand more less this problem, but i don´t know how to solve it.

```
private static readonly IDictionary<int, List<string>> permisosAccesoSolicitudesEstado = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>(){{0, new List<string>(){"A"}}, {1, new List<string>(){"B"}}};

private static bool esPermisoConcedido(List<string> usuariosPermitidos, string erfilUsuario)
    {
    return usuariosPermitidos.Any(x => x.Equals(perfilUsuario) || perfilUsuario.StartsWith(x + "|") || perfilUsuario.EndsWith("|" + x));
    }

public static bool puedeConsultar(int estadoActual, string perfilUsuario)
    {
    List<string> usuariosPermitidos = permisosAccesoSolicitudesEstado[estadoActual];
    return esPermisoConcedido(usuariosPermitidos, perfilUsuario);
    }

public static bool puedeConsultar(string estadoActual, string tipoUsuario)
    {
    return puedeConsultar(Convert.ToInt32(estadoActual), tipoUsuario);
    }

public Expression<Func<Solicitud, Boolean>> predicadoEstadoCorrectoSolicitud(string perfil)
        {
        return x=> EstadosSolicitud.puedeConsultar(x.estado, perfil);
        }

//Instantiated by reflection, this works fine
MethodInfo method = .....
Expression<Func<T, bool>> resultado = ConstructorPredicados.True<T>();
resultado = ConstructorPredicados.And(resultado, method);
objectSet.Where(resultado).ToList();
```

Note:

ConstructorPredicados is based in Monty´s Gush "A universal PredicateBuilder" on http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `EstadosSolicitud.puedeConsultar`? Your current code snippet looks incomplete / unrelated.

Comment: Yes, a bit incomplete. I thought it wasn´t necesary but here is the code to complete the problem. Thanks Ladislav.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Your `puedeConsultar` is .NET function. You cannot execute .NET functions in Linq-to-entities query. When you use method in Linq-to-entities you can use only methods which has direct mapping to SQL. It means that method in the query is only placeholder which is translated to execution of some SQL function. There is set of predefined method mappings called [cannonical functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx) and you can map your own SQL function when using EDMX but in your case you will most probably have to first load data to application by using ToList and after that execute `predicadoEstadoCorrectoSolicitud` on materialized result.